# How do I get hidden text from text field by robotframework

Tags: robotframework

[image]

I used this statement but got error

```
${searchbox_title}      Get Text     //form[@role='search']//input[@aria-label='ค้นหาใน เสื้อผ้าแฟชั่นผู้ชาย']
```

Error msg

```
Element with locator '//form[@role='search']//input[@aria-label='ค้นหาใน เสื้อผ้าแฟชั่นผู้ชาย']' not found.
```

Comment: I would try '//form[@role="search"]//input'. If that doesn't work, its probably under a iframe and in that case you need to enter the iframe before engaging with the element

Comment: I've tried //form[@role="search"]//input but I got Error "Element with locator '//form[@role="search"]//input' not found. How can I use I frame for this case, please.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to get the value from a dynamic element. The input field has that content after being written by the user or robot. Why not trying a different locator, for example:

```
//form[@role='search']/input[@class='shopee-searchbar-input___input']
```